# Custom keybinding in kitty

Tags: terminal, kitty

I'm currently switching from foot to kitty but I can't figure out how to transfer my custom keybindings for example in Foot I am using

clipboard-copy=Mod1+c
clipboard-paste=Mod1+v

Any advice would be greatly received